# backup and restore document+metadata from alfresco

Tags: alfresco

please it's been almost a month since I struggled on alfresco.
how can i backup and restore alfresco documents?
I would like to just save my documents+metadata and restore them in another ged (still alfresco)

Comment: Did you try https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-add/import-export-acp-zip-from-share/td-p/291773 ?

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation (https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/latest/admin/backup-restore/) is simple. You have to copy contentStore (documents), dump and copy database (metadata) and deal with solr (indexs). After restore you can reindex Alfresco witch means you only delete them (https://docs.alfresco.com/search-services/latest/admin/monitor/). Then you dont need them copy.

If you use old Alfresco (<=5.2) you can use BART (https://github.com/toniblyx/alfresco-backup-and-recovery-tool).
Otherwise if you use Alfresco in Docker via installer you can try this example (https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-blog/creating-and-restoring-backups-for-alfresco-with-docker-compose/ba-p/305070). It really depents of version and type of installation for both systems (source and destination Alfresco)